# Convert ISO date to yyyy-mm-dd format

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Given collection(#name: users) Structure:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57653dcc533304a40ac504fc"),
"username" : "XYZ",
"followers" : [ 
    {
        "count" : 31,
        "ts" : ISODate("2016-06-17T18:30:00.996Z")
    }, 
    {
        "count" : 31,
        "ts" : ISODate("2016-06-18T18:30:00.288Z")
    }
]
}
```

I want to query this collection based on username field, and ts to be returned in 'yyyy-mm-dd' format.
Expected Output:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57653dcc533304a40ac504fc"),
"username" : "XYZ",
"followers" : [ 
    {
        "count" : 31,
        "date" : "2016-06-17"
    }, 
    {
        "count" : 31,
        "date" : "2016-06-18"
    }
]
}
```

I have tried something like this:

```
db.users.aggregate([
{$match:{"username":"xyz"}},
{$project:{ "followers":{"count":1,
        "date":"$followers.ts.toISOString().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'-')"
          }}
}
])
```

But it doesn't seems to be working. Can anyone please help?
Thanks much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider running an aggregation pipeline that will allow you to flatten the data list first, project the new field using the **[`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)** operator, then regroup the flattened docs to get your desired result.

The above can be shown in three distinct pipelines:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "username": "xyz" } },
    { "$unwind": "$followers" },
    {
        "$project": {
            "username": 1,
            "count": "$followers.count",
            "date": { "$dateToString": { "format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$followers.ts" } }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "username": { "$first": "$username" },
            "followers": { "$push": {
                "count": "$count",
                "date": "$date"
            }}
        }
    }
])
```

---

With MongoDB 3.4 and newer, you can use the new **[`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/#pipe._S_addFields)** pipeline step together with **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)** to create the array field without the need to unwind and group:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "username": "xyz" } },    
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "followers": { 
                "$map": { 
                    "input": "$followers", 
                    "as": "follower",
                    "in": { 
                        "count": "$$follower.count", 
                        "date": { 
                            "$dateToString": { 
                                "format": "%Y-%m-%d", 
                                "date": "$$follower.ts" 
                            }
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: What would be the procedure for a vice-versa, that is converting a string in the format of yyyy-mm-dd to a Date in Mongo ?

Comment: @NixMan See [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) and [`$dateFromString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/#exp._S_dateFromString)

Comment: Thanks @chridam. Although, I was able to figure it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way to do this is to transform each element in the array with the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator. Of course in the "in" expression, you need to use the [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) to convert you "date" to string using a [format specifiers](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/#format-specifiers).

```
db.coll.aggregate(
    [ 
        { "$match": { "username": "XYZ" } }, 
        { "$project": { 
            "username": 1, 
            "followers": { 
                "$map": { 
                    "input": "$followers", 
                    "as": "f",
                    "in": { 
                        "count": "$$f.count", 
                        "date": { 
                            "$dateToString": { 
                                "format": "%Y-%m-%d", 
                                "date": "$$f.ts" 
                            }
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        }}
    ]
)
```

which produces:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("57653dcc533304a40ac504fc"),
    "username" : "XYZ",
    "followers" : [
        {
            "count" : 31,
            "date" : "2016-06-17"
        },
        {
            "count" : 31,
            "date" : "2016-06-18"
        }
    ]
}
```